Lower bound on the minimal value in the sequence $[\text{rank}(A + I), \text{rank}(A^{-1} + I)]$ for an arbitrary circulant binary matrix $A$
Let $n > 2$ denote an arbitrary even integer. Let $I$ denote the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Let $A$ denote an arbitrary invertible circulant binary (i.e. in the finite field $GF(2)$) matrix of dimension $n \times n$ such that the number of non-zero entries in every row of $A$ is odd. Is there a single formula (function) $f$ that, given the value of $n$, determines the lower bound on the minimal value in the sequence $$[\text{rank}(A + I), \text{rank}(A^{-1} + I)]$$ (addition is modulo $2$, i.e. bitwise XOR)? If yes, what is $f$?
EDIT
The question is based on the assumption that a particular $A$ is not given. In other words, given only the value of $n$, I want to know the minimal value in the sequence $$[\text{rank}(A_1 + I),\text{ rank}(A_1^{-1} + I),\text{ rank}(A_2 + I),\text{ rank}(A_2^{-1} + I),\text{ }\ldots,\text{ rank}(A_m + I), \text{rank}(A_m^{-1} + I)],$$ where $A_1, A_2,\text{ }\ldots,\text{ }A_m$ denote all matrices in the set of all invertible circulant binary matrices of dimension $n \times n$ such that the number of non-zero entries in every row of $A_i$ is odd $(1 \leq i \leq m)$. Is there an efficient algorithm that allows to compute this value?
